# how to create static line in coreplot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I am trying to make my control lines static so instead of being  displayed as part of the graph(the control lines are moving with the graph), they would be displayed like an axis

the app can only scroll horizontally

[image]

i'm talking about the two red line and the green line(which i put over the x axis)

this is how i do my lines:

```
// Center line
CPTScatterPlot *centerLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
centerLinePlot.identifier = kCenterLine;

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineWidth          = 2.0;
lineStyle.lineColor          = [CPTColor greenColor];


centerLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
centerLinePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:centerLinePlot];
```

but maybe it has something to do with the displayed range:

```
////////ajuste la portion a voir
if(data.Resultats.count>10)
{
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(data.Resultats.count - 10) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10)];
}

plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(RangeMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(RangeMax-RangeMin)];

// Adjust visible ranges so plot symbols along the edges are not clipped

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];

//place l'axe x sur la ligne de controle pour voir les WorkOrders
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(center);

//x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = yRange.location;
//y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = xRange.location;

//x.visibleRange = xRange;
//y.visibleRange = yRange;

//x.gridLinesRange = yRange;
//y.gridLinesRange = xRange;


[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.15)];//1.05
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.15)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's a limit on how far the main plot can scroll, just set the end points of the control lines outside that range. Core Plot will only draw the visible portion.

Another way to do this would be to add a second plot space to the graph. Add the control plots to this plot space instead of the default one. Set the `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` on it so it can't scroll.

Comment: thank you, since there is no limit for the scrolling i will try the second option. i'll post the result in a few minutes

Comment: i tried

CPTXYPlotSpace *ControlPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];    
    [graph addPlotSpace:ControlPlotSpace];

and changed

[graph addPlot:centerLinePlot];

to

[graph addPlot:centerLinePlot toPlotSpace:ControlPlotSpace];

but the control plot just disappeared

Comment: Did you set up the plot ranges on the new plot space?

Comment: yes i set globalrange with 0 and 50 for both and it didn't work. tried scaletofitplot but no success either. :(